# Currency symbol in kanban view odoo 8

Tags: currency, symbols, odoo-8, kanban

I need to add company currency symbol in kanban view.

```
<field name="company_currency_id" invisible="0" />
<field name="total_earnings" attrs="{'invisible':[('type_dashboard','!=','Total Earnings')]}" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'company_currency_id'}"
```

pls help

Answer (score 0):

In your case basically currency_id it always part of company related field.

which is always part of `company.currency` model

first added that field in your kanban view file and make it as invisible 
and that added your price field name using widget attribute.

```
<field name="currency_id" invisible="1" />
<field name="amount_total" nolabel="1"  widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
```

hear you can easily got the currency field after and before of field as per you are defined in your currency direction configuration for each currency.
amount_total is our price field we will get easily that field with currency configuration.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: Can we do this in list view also ?

Comment: Can we use widget  and then options in tree view so that we can able to see currency sign in tree view, Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes its possible i think you have to check the monetory widget in list view.

Comment: I am asking for v7 version and I looked into list view js. There is none kind of monetary type widget.

Comment: Yup there is one community module available for list view in V7. I had used it as as well but i forgot the name

Comment: Yes I gone through it and it works !! Also I want to know how we can apply this thing in tree view? Because as in openerp 7 both tree view and list view JS is different so I want to add that monitory sign in tree view. Do you have any idea regarding this ?

Comment: That what i am asking previously use the community module for the treeview as well.tree view and list view are the same. Please check the odoo apps you can easily find that module

Comment: I already checked and it is not working.. Yes both views are same but JS of both views is different, by default some of the widgets are there in list view js and none of widgets are there in tree view. By xml side both same but by JS both are different  in base and that module only help to add widget for monitory field defined in list view not in tree view. So again back to point do you have any idea regarding this ?

Comment: Can you please check the listview_monetory module from the odoo apps store and use it for v7.download and use it. It is free module from the store.

Comment: I already did that but I want to add monitory in 'Chart of analytic accounts' view and this app is not supporting this view because as I repeatedly saying 'Chart of analytic accounts'  is based on "**TREE**" view not in "**List**" view. **BOTH VIEW'S JS ARE DIFFERENT FROM BASE DEFINITION.** So that module not applicable in chart of analytic account.